# C++ Unable to display or read the whole txt file

Tags: c++

When the system tried to output, it only read the last line twice in the text file since I have two lines. I want to display all the movies. Thanks
programming language: C++
Container used:

```
string id, n;
std::string line;           
std::list<videoList> data;  
std::ifstream f ("output.txt"); 

while (getline (f, line)) {         
    std::string stmp;               
    std::stringstream ss (line);   
    getline(ss, id, ','); 
    getline(ss, movieTitle, ',');
    getline(ss, movieGenre, ',');
    getline(ss, movieProduction, ',');
    getline(ss, n);
    videoID = stoi (id);
    numberOfCopies = stoi(n);

    data.push_back(videoList(videoID, movieTitle, movieGenre, movieProduction, numberOfCopies));  
    
}

for (auto& d : data)    /* output all stored data */
    std::cout << "video id: " << videoID << "  movie title: " << movieTitle << "  movie genre: " << movieGenre
            << "  movie production: " << movieProduction<< "  number of copies: " << numberOfCopies << '\n';
```

[File:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vbrj.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVpI5.png)

Comment: What's your type of `videoList`, your print part has used the wrong variables, so it's always the last line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Take a look here:

```cpp
for (auto& d : data)    /* output all stored data */
    std::cout << "video id: " << videoID << "  movie title: " << movieTitle << "  movie genre: " << movieGenre
            << "  movie production: " << movieProduction<< "  number of copies: " << numberOfCopies << '\n';
```

You are iterating through the list of videos, i.e. `data`, and for each element you are writing to the console the values of some variables, `videoID`, `movieTitle`, etc. You are not using the object `d` here. Of course, these values hold the last movie that was read from the file, so you will print that N times, where N is the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Thank you so much Marius. I forgot to include the d. in the videoID.